# Getting Post request to work on an https server

Tags: http, https, client

I wrote a captcha application (as a RESTful service) and a PHP client that that make 2 types of call to the captcha application server.

1. Client requests a test from the server using this function

   function get_test_question( $myNumber )
   {

   ```
   $RequestIDResponse  = new RequestIDResponse();
   $url = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/myappl/abc/audio_check/{$myNumber}"
   ...
   ```

   }
2. Client sends its answer to the server and the server returns with either pass or fail using a function like this:

   function check_if_answer_is_correct( $answer = '' , $requestID = '' )

   {

   ```
   $url = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/myappl/abc/whats_answer";        
   ...
   ```

   }

When I implemented this in a server with regular HTTP connection worked fine.
Now, I need to host both the client and server on a ( the same) secure server (HTTPS).  I set it up the same way as I did on the non secure (HTTP) server and here is my experience:

The get request (#1 above) actually got a test from the server.  The user attempted the captcha test but in other to verify the answer, user clicks on submit button but the server isn't returning any feedback (pass or fail).

I am really a newbie to security but I have tried a couple of things that I saw online like: changing the port to 8181, using domain name instead of ip address, using https instead of http etc but none has worked.

I have also tested the client side on a none secure server (while hosting the captcha server on a secure server and using the functions above and communicating with HTTP, everything worked fine.

Therefore, in this situation where the post request isn't working when both client and server are on the same server (secure HTTPs), how can I solve this problem.  I look forward to your suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the answer is being submitted via https? you don't have hard-coded url's, right?

Comment: Yes the URL is hardcoded and at first I submitted the answer using https, when it didn't work I tried http but still did not work.

Comment: May be a little late, but did you end if fixing this?